# Magit: Is it possible to show 2 states of file? Before change and after change

Tags: magit

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1. , Magit

I have xml file. And I remove 8 lines and add 2 lines.

Here result in SmartGit:

[image: smartGit]

As you can see it's very simple to understand the state of file: before change and after change. It's very convenient.

Now how this file look in Magit:

[image: Magit]

As you can see all changes are in ONE buffer. It's not very convenient.

The question is: Is it possible to show change in 2 buffers? One buffer to show content of file before change and another buffer to show file after change. Like in SmartGit.

Thanks

Comment: This question is addressed by my answer to your other question from yesterday.

Comment: This is a different question. Yesterday I ask for indent. Today I ask for 2 buffers.

Comment: It is a different question indeed, but answering that other question involved answering this question even though you had not asked it yet. I said something to the effect of "Magit does not support showing two versions of a file in two separate buffers and marking the areas that changed between the two buffers/versions. However it does support Ediff, which does support that (it is its primary purpose). Press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter Ediff."

Answer (score 4):

Magit does not support showing two versions of a file in two separate buffers and marking the areas that changed between the two buffers/versions. However it does support Ediff, which does support that (it is its primary purpose). Press <kbd>e</kbd> on a change in Magit to enter Ediff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ediff to show you the two versions of the file side-by-side. Press <kbd>e</kbd> when your cursor is on the line of the file you want to view.